# How to center an animated image and unanimated text on a webpage, regardless of the device type, in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, device, centering

I tried putting the animated image into a table, but the animation doesn't work in that case.

I can only use HTML and CSS to make this work.

I'm wanting to center the green, spinning circle on the page both vertically and horizontally, have the logo sit without spinning inside of the circle, and have text that changes every 5 seconds right beneath it, centered horizontally and not too far vertically from the edge of the circle.

Right now, with the following code, the mobile version looks like:

[image: Mobile View]

(The red circle circles the logo, which is also appearing smaller than I want it to be)

The desktop view currently looks like:

[image: Desktop View]

As you can see here, the logo is still slightly off center vertically and the circle is really close to the top of the screen, rather than center.

So far I have in HTML:

```
<div id="animatedLogo">
    <div id="loadingCircle">
        <img id="loadingLogo" src="../Content/images/HCSS_GooglePresentation_Spinner_Green.PNG" class="circle" />
    </div>
    <div id="wordLogo">
        <img id="HCSSLogo" src="../Content/images/hcss logo2.jpg" class="logo" />
    </div>
    <div id="myPhrase" class="phrase"></div>
</div>




<div class="main-container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <form method="post" action="{responseUri}">
                {responseFields}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="../Content/please-wait.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/logoAnimation.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/formPostResponse.js"></script>
```

And in CSS I have:

```
#animatedLogo {
    text-align: center;
}

#loadingLogo {
    animation: rotation 2.5s infinite linear;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 35%;
    padding: 1% 0;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

#loadingCircle {
    min-height: 77%;
    min-width: 35%;
}

#wordLogo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 67%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*padding: 5% 0;*/
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.circle {
}

.logo {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 11% 0;
}

.phrase {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: oblique;
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 625px; */
    margin-left: 50%;
    /* text-align: center; */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

(Added 3:58 pm on 6/20) In addition, I need to make sure the circle doesn't alter its shape and become an oval like it did here when I changed my solution to fit a suggested answer:

[image: Circle Became an Oval]

Added at 8:19 a.m. on 6/21/18The circle no longer becomes an oval! However, nothing is centered now.
[image: 2nd Update]

**Update as of 9:24 am**

We're getting closer!! 
[image: Desktop View 9:12 am 6/21]
[image: Mobile View 9:12 am 6/21]

1) I realize that I probably should pick a certain ratio of the size of the logo to the size of the spinner to use so that the logo doesn't get so small on mobile versions. I'm searching the web for ideas, but if you know of one particularly fitting for this project, let me know!

2) Now we need to get the phrases under the spinner, rather than out to the side.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with another fix, hope that works!

Comment: Updated my answer again, this should work. If not: let me know, we'll fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 3**

Bring the phrase out of the centered class like this:

```
<div id="centered">
    <div id="animatedLogo">
      <div id="loadingCircle">
          <img id="loadingLogo" src="../Content/images/HCSS_GooglePresentation_Spinner_Green.PNG" class="circle" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wordLogo">
    <img id="HCSSLogo" src="../Content/images/hcss logo2.jpg" class="logo" />
  </div>

</div>
<div id="myPhrase" class="phrase">phrase phrase phrase phrasephrase</div>
```

Then in the css change this:

```
.phrase {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova", sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vmin;
  font-style: oblique;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

To change things on smaller screens use media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .someClass {
          color: red;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Okay, I tested things out and this should work:

html:

```
<div id="centered">
    <div id="animatedLogo">
      <div id="loadingCircle">
          <img id="loadingLogo" src="../Content/images/HCSS_GooglePresentation_Spinner_Green.PNG" class="circle" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wordLogo">
    <img id="HCSSLogo" src="../Content/images/hcss logo2.jpg" class="logo" />
  </div>
  <div id="myPhrase" class="phrase"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#centered {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wordLogo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* height: 67%; */
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; */
  /*padding: 5% 0;*/
  /* margin-top: 5%; */
}
```

**update**

Try this out if flexbox is not working:

```
#loadingCircle, #wordLogo {
  position: relative;
}
#loadingCircle img, #wordLogo img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Try using flexbox:

```
#loadingCircle, #wordLogo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: It looks like it centered the logo and the changing slogan text, but not the circle itself.

Comment: Inserting a picture of what the screen looks like after using the updated fix you posted.

Comment: Update 3 pretty much worked for me! I had to add some more media queries and do a lot of resizing, but I have everything but the phrase in a good place. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, if you got another question feel free to ask. And oh, could you mark the answer as accepted to finish this for now?